# Realtime network scanner in python

Tags: networking, python-3.x

I want to write a small tool which tells me everytime when someone joins the same subnet/network. I could to this with time managed network scans but that wouldn't be real time.

Is there an easy solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

When some device join the subnet, it should first send the ARP request of its gateway

You can listen and analyze the **ARP** packets to identity the new joined devices.

Comment: That was also my idea to listen for the broadcast packages like arp or dhcp request. The thing is how do I implement this in python?

Comment: To make it simple , you can use  other  tools to handle packet  sniffing and  output   the  packet  data to you  python  module. You should handle this  data analyze yourself.

Comment: for packet capture  tools,  you  can  try tcpdump on linux or  dumpcap(find it in wireshark) on windows